# Panda pivot table margins only on row

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Anyone knows how to do margins on panda pivot table only on row?
current setting will calculate both row and column margin
Thanks !

Answer (score 9):

You can remove them by indexing with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','b','a','a'],
    'B': ['a','d','d','b']
})

df = pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B'], margins=True)
print (df)
B    a  b  d  All
A                
a    1  1  1    3
b    0  0  1    1
All  1  1  2    4

df1 = df.iloc[:, :-1]
print (df1)
B    a  b  d
A           
a    1  1  1
b    0  0  1
All  1  1  2

df2 = df.iloc[:-1]
print (df2)
B  a  b  d  All
A              
a  1  1  1    3
b  0  0  1    1
```